# Disable Filter in Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning,

I am working on a new site and using a child theme for my amendments. I wish to remove a filter that is operating on the parent theme - is there an amendment I can make to my child theme functions to do this?

The function in the parent theme is:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'rosette_setup' ) ) :
function rosette_setup() {

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ){
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_bar_nav'){
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="'.get_permalink(2798).'" title="">My Account</a></li>';
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="'.get_permalink(5).'" title="">My Wishlist</a></li>';
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a class="nav-top-link" href="'.wp_logout_url().'">Log Out</a></li>';
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_bar_nav') {
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="'.get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ).'" title="">Login</a></li>';
    }
return $items;
}

}
endif; 
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'rosette_setup' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the  remove_filter() function anywhere should do just that... So for your code you will be looking at

```
function my_child_theme_setup() {
    remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10 );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

Just place that code in your child-theme's function.php file and filter is removed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I tried the code above and unfortunately it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I see. There are two other ways you may want to try. One is disabling the function completely. 

You may need to add this code to your child theme

`if ( ! function_exists( 'rosette_setup' ) ) :
function rosette_setup() {
return;
}
endif;`

Comment: Since the functions in the child theme loads up first it makes the function with that name and does nothing. So when the parent function loads up it checks for the function name and skips if it exists. Do not use if your function has other functions in it that will be needed by the install.

Comment: This did not work for me but I appreciate you taking the time to look at it for me.